# PHP background process similar to Nodejs

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I suspect my question is rather rudimentary, but here it goes: In Node.js I can start a process and have it run in the background waiting for requests. For example, I can create a variable and increment it by 1 every time I get a request. How can I do the same in PHP? From what I understand PHP code is run just for the request, then everything is removed from memory. Thank you!

Comment: Use a permanent storage (files, database)

Comment: Isn't there a better way to do this other than using a database? I imagine a database is rather slow if you have multiple requests per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is just a programming language, similar to JavaScript.

Node.js is an application server that is capable of running JavaScript applications, and allows you to listen to requests etc. as you described.

To achieve the same functionality with PHP, you will also need an application server. You could look into e.g. the [Apache Web Server](https://httpd.apache.org/) or [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/).

Comment: I set up a local Apache server, but the problem still stands. Is it possible to write a PHP file similar to a javascript(used by Node.js) one that is run continuously and is waiting for requests?

Comment: Well, that's kind of mutually exclusive. Do you want to run the script when a request comes in, or all the time?

Comment: Actually I want it to wait for requests and when they come I want the script to change the values of some variables and then remember these new values. Someone suggested using a database, but isn't that too slow for a real-time multiplayer game for example?

Comment: PHP has options for cross-session in-memory storage, look into [shared memory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php) or [semaphores](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php). However, you will likely need permanent storage of your data anyway. Databases are not as slow as you probably think. In your position, I would start of with a standard database in the backend and think about alternatives (which certainly will add complexity) when you actually face performance issues in practice.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm going with the databases then.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a server process with PHP. For example applications created using the Symfony framework [benefit from using a console script](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#running-the-symfony-application) to launch a Web server for development purposes.